# Connect Virtual Network (Classic) to Virtual Network (Classic) in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

How can I connect to classic virtual networks in the Azure portal? All the documentation I can find seems to reference the old portal, which is not accessible anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manage.windowsazure.com is running as always. Here is a step by step reference on how to connect the vnets: [Configure a VNet-to-VNet connection in the Azure Classic Portal](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/)

Comment: thanks! It turns out I had to go back and use the old portal to do this

Comment: yes, can manage the 'old' vnets from the manage.windowsazure.com and the new vnets from the resource manager portal (new)